# Get error TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

When I do this, `I get “ts-ignore - error TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'`

```
type Obj = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
  key3: string | null;
};
type Keys = keyof Obj;
function mutateObj(obj: Obj, key: Keys, value: any) {
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

I get the error above. When I remove null from key3, it works fine. if you do `key3?: string;` I get the same error. I know I am doing something wrong, and it relates to null / undefined type, but not sure how to resolve.

Update: Thanks for the implementation.
The actual use case is inside immer reducer in react app, 
and I wonder if there is a way to type this without helper function.
(for now, I am using the function to mutate the draft in the first answer. Thanks a lot! :-) )

```
const myReducer = produce((draft:<Obj>, action:{type:”update_prop”; prop: Keys, value: any })=>{
  switch (action.type) {
    case “update_prop” :
      // below gets type error
      draft[action.prop] = action.value;
      return;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could implement it this way

```
type Obj = {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
  key3: string | null;
};

function mutateObj<T extends Obj, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
  obj[key] = value;
}

const o: Obj = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: '2',
    key3: null,
};

mutateObj(o, 'key1', 'zz');
```

Additionally it would retain type-safety of the values.